# RB tree with sum

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, red-black-tree

I have some questions about augmenting data structures:

---

**Let S = {k1, . . . , kn}** be a set of numbers. Design an efficient
data structure for S that supports the following two operations:

**Insert(S, k)** which inserts the
**number k into S (you can assume that k is not contained in S yet), and TotalGreater(S, a)**
which returns the sum of all keys **ki ∈ S** which are larger than a, that is, **P ki∈S, ki>a ki** .

Argue the running time of both operations and give pseudo-code for **TotalGreater(S, a)** (do not given pseudo-code for **Insert(S, k)**).

---

I don't understand how to do this, I was thinking of adding an extra field to the RB-tree called sum, but then it doesn't work because sometimes I need only the sum of the left nodes and sometimes I need the sum of the right nodes too.

So I was thinking of adding 2 fields called leftSum and rightSum and if the current node is > GivenValue then add the cached value of the sum of the sub nodes to the current sum value.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a variable `size` to each node, which is the number of nodes in the subtree rooted at that node. When finding the node with the smallest value that is larger than the value `a`, two things can happen on the path to that node: you can go left or right. Every time you go left, you add the size of the right child + 1 to the running total. Every time you go right, you do nothing.

There are two conditions for termination. 1) we find a node containing the exact value `a`, in which case we add the size of its right child to the total. 2) we reach a leaf, in which case we add 1 if it is larger than `a`, or nothing if it is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

As Jordi describes: The key-word could be augmented red-black tree.